Is this a mistake or am I misunderstanding how to calculate a capacitor's impedance with ESR and ESL?
The following is from a pdf by Texas Instruments:

If Z is the magnitude of the impedance, the terms under the square root should be squared, like this:

Or am I misunderstanding something?

Fault impression ...

You are correct, TI definitely messed up on the calculation. A simple unit check reveals this. \$R\$ has unit \$\Omega\$, \$\omega L\$ has units \$\Omega\$ and \$-\frac{1}{\omega C} \$ has units \$\Omega\$, so according to TI \$Z \$ must have units \$\sqrt{\Omega}\$ which is obviously incorrect.

It's just a typo in the data sheet.
It can simply be a copy-paste error or font being incorrect - only the squared to the power of two symbol is missing.
Mind you, the file is one day less 24 years old now.
The file metadata indicates it was produced in year 2000, August 30th, in Adobe Acrobat Distiller 3.02b for Solaris 2.3 and later.
Things were a bit different back then regarding computing, copy-pasting exotic symbols might not have been so ubiquitous like we can assume today, and it still might not be perfect.

The absolute value symbols are also missing around the Z

@ThePhoton Why would it matter? The R is a positive real number and R squared is always positive real number and the X is a positive or negative real number and X squared is always positive real number, therefore the sum from which you take the square root is positive real number and thus the Z is always a positive and real number, indicating the magnitude of impedance Z.

Z is a complex number R + jX. It's only a real number at resonance when $X_c$ and $X_l$ are equal and opposite. THe formula gives the magnitude of Z, not the actual Z.

@ThePhoton OK I see, technically you are right in the context of complex numbers and the notation about taking the magnitude. However the application note simply gives you a bunch of formulas to calculate a plottable impedance vs frequency, never mentioning complex numbers.
